# Summation problem: $\sum_{k=1}^6 (k-1)/(k+1)$

Tags: summation

How do I solve:

$\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{k-1}{k+1}$

Thanks

Comment: There are only $6$ numbers to add, one of which is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no other way than to just add the '6' summands.$$\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{k-1}{k+1} = 0 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4} + \dots = \frac{197}{70}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{k-1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{k+1-2}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^6 (1+ \frac{-2}{k+1})=6-2\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{1}{k+1}$